# curl is not working with PHP Version 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2

Tags: curl, php-7

I recently have upgraded to the PHP Version 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2...since then the curl is not working in the server...while checking in the server it says curl is installed but while using the following script there is no output...

```
try
{

$ch = curl_init(); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://in.yahoo.com"); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        curl_close($ch);      
        echo $output;
}
catch(Thrwoable $t)
{

    echo 'Exception', $ex->getMessage(),"\n";
}
```

It does not even returning any error...can you please help me to figure out whats wrong here...is there anything wrong with this php7 version?

Comment: did you upgrade your extensions? i.e. `apt-get install php7.0-curl` and is this php module enabled?

Comment: @ash...I ran this command apt-get install php7.0-curl and it ran successfully...and how to check the php module enable?

Answer (score 0):

finally, I have figured out the solution and posting it here so that it may help others in future...

php -m

vi /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini

xdebug.show_error_trace = 1

sudo apt-get install php-soap php-curl

And it works like a charm now...thanks @ash for hinting me to check php module enabled...